# Convert my sql query to laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to convert a normal sql to laravel query .Property is the model name . ..please let me know for this query to laravel model query

```
SELECT * FROM property WHERE
property.active = 1 AND 
on_market = 1 AND
department = 'lettings' AND
price > 0 AND
( submitted_at IS NULL OR submitted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR ( submitted_at IS NOT NULL AND approved_at IS NOT NULL ) )enter code here
```

Comment: We're not a code-writing service. Please try something yourself first, and when you get stuck, we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query, which uses a raw WHERE:

```
DB::table('property')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->where('on_market', '=', 1)
        ->where('department', '=', 'lettings')
        ->where('price', '>', 0)
        ->where(DB::raw("COALESCE(submitted_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR approved_at IS NOT NULL"))
        ->get();
```

The second half of the `OR` in your final `WHERE` condition I think can be reduced to `approved_at IS NOT NULL` since `submitted_at` would already be not `NULL` in order for this condition to be considered.

Also, there is a code smell if you really expect `submitted_at` to have the value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  Ideally, you would only have to check for `NULL`, but in any case my use of `COALESCE()` should match your intended logic.

Comment: would you evaluate my answer? I'm interested in this topic since had too many problems in the past building queries in eloquent way and I'm trying to improve it every day. Thanks

Comment: i have a another quey .SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, (((acos(sin((51.4251835*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((51.4251835*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((-0.1307054- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM `property`)myTable WHERE distance <= 2 LIMIT 15  ..please will you convert this also for property model

Comment: @DgDinesh You _absolutely_ should ask a new question for this.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing forum where you keep asking new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
Property::where('active',1)
    ->where('on_market',1)
    ->where('department','lettings')
    ->where('price','>',0)
    ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->isNull('submitted_at')
              ->orWhere('submitted_at','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
              ->orWhere(function ($query2) {
                  $query2->whereNotNull('submited_at')->whereNotNull('approved_at')
            })
})->get();
```

Comment: This might be valid, but it could be simplified and I would not write it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```html
use property;
use DB;
DB::table('property')
->where('on_market ', '=', 1)
->where('active', '=', 1)
->where('department', 'lettings')
->where('price', '=', 0)
->orWhereNotNull('submitted_at')
->or_where('submitted_at' '=','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
->orWhereNotNull('submitted_at')
   ->whereNotNull('approved_at')
```

Comment: This will not build a subquery, I doubt it will work like above in question.

Comment: The potential problem with this is that the order of operations of AND/OR may lead to incorrect logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this can help you

```
$sql_query =  DB::table('property AS p')
                        ->select('*')
                        ->where('p.active','=',1)
                        ->where('on_market','=','lettings')
                        ->where('price','>',0)
                        ->where(DB::raw("COALESCE(submitted_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR approved_at IS NOT NULL"))
                        ->get();

    $sql_query = json_decode(json_encode($sql_query), true);
```

in the variable `$sql_query` you will get the result array

Comment: I have'nt seen your answer, post here did'nt got updated when I posted